# Display command in bash not working anymore

Tags: bash

I'm using a bash script with `display` command, after upgrading to `Ubuntu 10.10` this bash script ends with error message:

`display: command not found`

Where could be the fault?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't installed the anything that provides the 'display' command.

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/display 
imagemagick: /usr/bin/display
```

Installing "imagemagick" should allow you to use 'display' again.